# Reactivity in properties not working between controls

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been trying to make my property reactive but for some reason, it does not work. My property is used between two Vue components. I can access the components fine but it's just this property

In the child component, I have a dropdown and I select a user from this. I want to pass it to the parent component

The drop down is a custom control hence it would not be possible to paste its code. But as soon as the user is selected, an event is fired and I can see in the debugger that the even is fired successfully with user selected. Now the problem is passing the value to the parent.

The event in the child component:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["selectedParentControl"]),
},
methods {
  onUserSelected(items){
    Vue.set( this.selectedParentControl, 'userObject', items )
  }
}
```

Parent template:

```
<div v-if="userObject"> 
   <p class="mb-0">First User: {{this.userObject}}</p>
</div>
```

But the variable in the parent component doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

So if I got you right you want to setup two-way data binding for your custom component. So you can use the `v-model`.

In your child component define the prop and emit value changes.

```js
props: ['userObject'],
methods {
  onUserSelected(items){
    this.$emit('userObject', items);
  }
}
```

In your parent component add the `v-model` directive to your child components element:

```js
<div v-if="userObject"> 
   <child v-model="userObject"></child>
   <p class="mb-0">First User: {{this.userObject}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want to add this to the store. I want to use similar to v-model in the javascript